# In an excel outline (VBA generated) , how can I use subtotal (109) instead of (9)?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am using VBA to automatically subtotal some data in a spreadsheet.
Im currently have ...Function:=xlSum which places the *subtotal* formula in the appropriate cells etc.

The problem is that this formula by default uses function_num **9** whereas I want **109** (so hidden values are not included).

It may seem strange that I want to exclude hidden values, but there is definitely method to my madness.

Here is my what I have:

```
Selection.Subtotal _
    GroupBy:=groupColumn, Function:=xlSum, _
    TotalList:=Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), _
    Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
```

Can anyone suggest a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a `Selection.Replace "SUBTOTAL(9,", "SUBTOTAL(109,", xlPart` at the end.

Comment: Yes! That works perfectly! Such a simple solution as well.What exactly does xlPart do. Forgive me, I'm pretty new to VBA.

Comment: It tells the code that you want to look for, and replace, part of the cell rather than only matching entire cell contents.